# What is using the kubernetes pod mount folder?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, mount

I have found an orphaned pod in my kubernetes cluster on one node. When I try to clean it up I see the following behavior:

```
# rm -rf /var/lib/kubelet/pods/a1fce4c0-2f64-11e9-9880-005056aed74b/
rm: cannot remove ‘/var/lib/kubelet/pods/a1fce4c0-2f64-11e9-9880- 
005056aed74b/volumes/kubernetes.io~fc/harbor-jobservice-pv’: Device or resource busy
```

Trying to check what's using it I get nothing:

```
# lsof +D /var/lib/kubelet/pods/a1fce4c0-2f64-11e9-9880-005056aed74b/volumes/kubernetes.io~fc/harbor-jobservice-pv
#
```

Checking the mountpoints I get nothing:

```
# mount | grep -i a1fce4c0
# cat /proc/mounts | grep -i a1fce4c0
#
```

The folder is not a symlink, `ls -a` shows it's empty. I was validating a theory that this mount is created by kubelet, but after stopping it, I still haven't been able to clean it up. It doesn't seem to be a docker volume either (by inspecting the volumes from `docker volume inspect <volume>`.

Rebooting the node is not what I'm looking for - I'd like to understand the problem, not just work-around it.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: The persistent volume in scope of that orphaned pod is now bound to a new pod:

```
# kubectl get pv harbor-jobservice-pv
NAME                   CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS    
CLAIM                          STORAGECLASS   REASON    AGE
harbor-jobservice-pv   5Gi        RWO            Retain           Bound     
harbor/harbor-jobservice-pvc
```

This PV/PVC pair is used by

```
# kubectl get pod -n harbor harbor-harbor-jobservice-6b9c8598c8-x5l64 -o 
yaml
...
metadata:
    uid: bb60bfdd-4c8e-11e9-8b8e-005056aea3a7
...
spec:
  volumes:
  - name: job-logs
    persistentVolumeClaim:
    claimName: harbor-jobservice-pvc
...
```

So you can see that the pod using this PV is different from the pod in whose folder I have the held folder.

Comment: Can you run a describe on the pod you are trying to delete? It might be mounting the volume?

Comment: The pod is not present anymore in the list of running pods on the cluster. That's why it's labeled as an 'orphaned' pod. However because of the fact that I can't find the referenced pod and containers running, I'm unable to get my head around the folder in use.

Comment: Can you try `kubectl get pv --all-namespaces`, are you expecting to have the pod used by `harbor-jobservice-pv`?

Comment: Just added more information to the question as per your comment.

Comment: Have you tried removing the persistent volume and the pod altogether? `kubectl delete pvc -n harbor harbor-jobservice-pvc; kubectl delete pv harbor-jobservice-pv; kubectl delete pod a1fce4c0-2f64-11e9-9880-005056aed74b; rm -rf /var/lib/kubelet/pods/a1fce4c0-2f64-11e9-9880-005056aed74b/;`